# How to grab all instances of a partial class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm trying to reinitialize a variable that gets all instances of a class name. Here's my code for reinit:

```
newContent = $(".product-sample-field[class^='appended']");
```

And for reference, my HTML looks like this:

```
<tr class="product-sample-field appended1">...</tr>
<tr class="product-sample-field appended2">...</tr>
<tr class="product-sample-field appended3">...</tr>
```

And so forth.

So I'm trying to grab all instances of .product-sample-field and .appended where .appended is dynamically getting a number appended to the class name.

Comment: As an aside to the question, it's cases like this where incremental id and class attributes are an anti-pattern. I'd strongly suggest you change the classnames to all be the same and use DOM traversal to relate/target the necessary elements

Comment: If you feel you *must* use an incremental id (*protip: you don't*) - then change your `.addClass("appended" + idx)` to `.addClass("appended appended" + idx)` and make your life much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns all instances under .product-sample-field and class names start with "appended". Use * instead of ^.

```
$(".product-sample-field[class*='appended']");
```

Comment: Aaah, got it. Thank you!